# Python While Statements

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused on the logic of doing this.

I want the user to be able to input the number of items they have, and then ask them at the end if they are done. Right now I'm asking after every single item, and I don't like it.

How should I modify this code to get what I want?

Input:

```
if next1 == "2":
    next2=input("How many would you like to add? ")
    val = int(next2)
    print("")
    count = 0
    while count < int(next2):
        count = count + 1
        next3=input(str(count) + ". Input: ")
    print("")
    check=input("Are you sure? (Y/N) ")
    while check not in ("YyYesNnNo"):
        check=input("Are you sure? (Y/N) ")
    if check in ("YyYes"):
        add(next3)
        home()
    elif check in ("NnNo"):
        sort(numbers)
        home()
```

Function:

```
def add(next2):
    numbers.append(next2)
    sort(numbers)
    home()
```

Comment: while check not in ("YyYesNnNo")...what should this do?

Comment: Checks if they didn't put one of those letters, I meant to add list at the front but thats besides the point.

Comment: what is your error? or problem? I am unclear what you are asking

Comment: Did you read what I said at all @JoranBeasley

Comment: I'm totally unclear what you are trying to ask? Can you try rephrasing your question, please. It would help if you could state exactly what the problem is and what you want to do?

Comment: Also, btw, the `( )`s in `check in ("YyYes")` are spurious, you can just do `check in "YyYes"`.

Comment: @JackAidley thats really off the point, but as I said already twice, I want to ask are your sure (Y/N) and if they say yes it passes the function add to the number they input but the issue is I can't have it in a while statement or else it will ask everytime they input a number. If you just look at the code you will understand. And if you don't understand by looking than I'm sure you can't help me.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? I sort of understand your question but don't see how the code you posted would have that result. Both while loops only have 2 and 1 statements inside them at the moment. Unless `home` is also doing some flow control...

Comment: Home is also, although I'm not pasting the whole code, that would be huge. Its only the code right there that needs to be changed.

Comment: since you have clearly stated that anyone who doesnt understand what you are asking is unqualified to answer.  I dont think anyone on SO is qualified to answer your question... maybe try asking the class instructor for assistance since he will understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I said if you don't understand from what code is shown than I'm not sure you're good enough to be able to answer this question. Meaning that if you don't understand what this code is doing than you clearly don't know what you're talking about. Seeing on how most of the comments on this were completely off topic like @JohnJohn2 and Jack Aidleys comments. And this isn't for class Joran.

Comment: Most people when they make comments are genuinely trying to understand the question. I know it's hard not to get defensive but nobody is attacking you, really.

Comment: Some advice for life, user2812028, if people are asking you to clarify it's because _you aren't explaining well_ not because the people asking you to clarify are idiots. Stick to this simple principle and you'll find (a) you get help from people more easily and (b) you learn to be better at communicating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, well generally you might do something like this

```
def confirm_with_user():
    user_data = ""
    while user_data not in "YyYesNnNo":
        user_data = input("Are you sure? (Y/N) ")

    return user_data.lower() in "yes":
```

Then at the point in your code when you want to confirm with your user you just do

```
if confirm_with_user():
    #proceed...
else:
    #They don't want to proceed
```

Comment: nice answer :) although wording the question slightly differently would have yielded a quicker answer for OP with less downvotes

Comment: Agreed... He'll get there I'm sure.